# Ajax not posting to Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on learning AJAX and I'm having trouble understanding how to throw errors in script that runs off page. I can't get the data to update my DB, but can't seem to get an error either. I'm not sure hwo to dump and debug when it's running off page as it will in this AJAX scenario. I'm new to AJAX so it's possible the problem is there as well. Is there an equivalent within jquery using AJAX to determine this?

```
***Update**

    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['clueOne'])) {
    include "includes/db_conx.php";

            $usernameClue = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['usernameClue']);
            $clueOne = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['clueOne']);
                // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system

                // Add this product into the database now

                $sqls = "UPDATE usersClueGame SET clueOne = '1' WHERE username = $usernameClue;";

                $result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqls) or die("Couldn't execute query.");;
                exit();
    }
    ?>
```

.js

```
// =====clue 1====================////////////////// clue 1**********************************************************************========================
$(document).on('click', '.btn-clue', function(){ 
    if($i!=1){
        //checking if textbox has desired value (1 in this case),
        //in your application you would be passing the textbox value to ajax here and making the check at server side
        var $one = $('#oneClueShow');
        var x = $("#clueOneInput").find('input[type=text]').val();
        if(x == 'd' || x == 'dr')

        {
            //if answer correct you should load data from ajax and append it to a container
            $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "includes/post_clue_progress.php",
                      data: { clueOne: "1", usernameClue: "<?php echo $manager; ?>" }
                    })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    // msg is any data that is echoed in the php script or output to screen is some way
                    $("#clueWrongOne").hide();
                    $("#mySecondDiv").remove();
                    $("#clueOne").remove();
                    $("#clue1Input").remove();
                    $one.show();
                    $("#clueOneInputCorrect").slideDown('slow').show();
                    $i++;
                  });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mySecondDiv").remove();
            var mySecondDiv = $('<div id="mySecondDiv"><img src="images/check-x-mark.png" /></div>').show('slow');
            $('#clueWrongOne').append(mySecondDiv);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You need `$usernameClue` in your sql statement, `$username` seems to be undefined.

Comment: Use your browser's development tools to determine what URL your AJAX call is using (check the 'Network' tab), and paste that URL into your browser's address bar. View the results and/or error messages that are returned and compare them to what your JS is expecting. If no errors or data are displayed, check your php.ini file and correct your error_reporting and display_errors settings.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that @jeroen . This is actually something that I changed for better understanding here. This is correct on my end.

Comment: You should post your real code here, otherwise it will be hard to help you, especially if you introduce errors that are not in your original code.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins parameters clueOne 1
usernameClue chris seem to all be fine. The URL AJAX is calling is correct. The post_clue_progress.php is correctly running.

Comment: Sorry @jeroen I was trying to make it as clear as possible as to what was supposed to be happening. Everything other than that variable which ahs been correct is the same.

Comment: Looking things over I'm now confused as to the loop here. Should I be using a GET for the data coming to the off page php script? Maybe that is the issue?